# Jasper Report Contitional Styles with named style references from path

Tags: java

I have many jasper report that use the generic Style Reference Name(Ex:style_2.jrtx ) for all .jrxml, but i need to use another font (.ttf) according to an 'X' condition,
    so i'm forced to use another Style Reference Name(style_1.jrtx). I tried to create a java fonction from a Scriptlts, for exemple:

```
  public String getStyle() 
  {    
    String m="ttt";
    if (m.equals(ttt))
    {
         return "style_1.jrtx";
    }
    else {
         return "style_2.jrtx";
    }
  }
```

After i called this function in the source expression of template Style : 
Example: `$P{REPORT_SCRIPTLET}.getStyle()`, please check the screenshot
[example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DPSjI.jpg)

This does not work for me, I have an error:

> Error filling print... Could not resolve style(s):
>       Any suggestions please. I use iReport 5.6.

Comment: `if (m.equals(ttt))` what is `ttt` here? is it variable ?

Comment: sorry "ttt". But  that is not the most important, I use only an example of a function that returns (String) a value or another